# Filter out id from result mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I'm trying to filter out the _id from my result but I'd like a little bit of syntax help. I tried making a builder but the syntax is incorrect:

```
   public void FetchResult()
    {
        //Fetch database collection
        var test_collection = Client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection");

        //filder results
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", false);

        //Find all Bson Documents
        var documents = test_collection.Find(filter).ToList();
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: To remove a field from the output, you need to use _projection_ - `ProjectionDefinition` or `ProjectionDefinitionBuilder`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? @prasad_

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912225/2282634

Comment: See Projections sub-topic in [Definitions and Builders](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/driver/definitions/)

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately no because it requires having the class of the object.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
//specify blank search criteria to match all documents in the db
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;

//specify a projection that will exclude the id field
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id");

//execute find command with filter and projection
var documents = test_collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and it's also a clear way of adding filters and projections.